# Get data from any cell in Grid Control of DevExpress

Tags: grid, devexpress, gridcontrol

I want to get data from any cell in DevExpress Grid control to assign to a textbox. 
So how to get any cell data can be passed through it's address?

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a cell value use the [GridView.GetRowCellValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.GetRowCellValue.overloads) method.

Answer (score 1):

I may be jumping ahead, but it sounds like you may want to take the text from a given column in a highlighted row and apply it to a text box somewhere else on the form.

If this is the case, I highly recommend a binding source.  Bind the actual data to the binding source, then make the binding source the `DataSource` for both your grid and your text box.

If you go to the text box's DataBinding->Advanced Property, you will see how to bind it to the appropriate property.  When you click on various rows in the grid, you will change the `.Current` property of the binding source, which will automatically update the text in the text box.

Or, one better, use the Dev Express DataLayout, which does the heavy lifting (and much more) for you.

Answer (score 0):

TextBox.Text=GridView_Name.GetRowCellValue(GridView_Name.FocusedRowHandle, GridView_Name.Columns[Number of column]).ToString();**This is the answer**